# Find a range of value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two different sheets with 300,000 data in Excel. 
   First sheet contains:

```
    S2_Symbol   Start_Pos   End Position
    STE        254857     267891
    PRI        748578     758962
    ILA        852741     963369
    VIS        789456     796325
```

Second:

```
   S1_Location
   789460
   852898
   748678
```

My output should be like this:

```
S1_Location   Symbol 
789460         VIS
852898        ILA
748678        PRI
```

I have to find that `S1_location` falls in which `S2_location` and its corresponding Symbol. I have used INDEX formula in Excel but for each cell, I have to change the reference cell manually. I couldn't do it 300,000 data.

How can I do in an in Excel or should I use a script?

Comment: Sorry. Ive missed one digit in my output example.Now check the output example. I can sort the first sheet by Start-Pos. But how can i get the required output?

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes the following:

- Start and End Positions for each `S2 Symbol` are unique *(i.e. there is no intersection between the ranges allocated to each symbol)*
- Data in first sheet is located at `A1:D17` *(adjust ranges in formulas as needed)*
- Data in second sheet is locate at `A1:B300010` *(adjust ranges in formulas as needed)*

The solution requires:

- To add a working column in worksheet one. Enter this formula in `D2` and copy till last record.

  ```
  =ROWS($A$1:$A2)
  ```

  [image]

*Fig. 1*

- Then in second worksheet enter this formula at `B2` and copy till last record.

  ```
  =INDEX( Sheet1!$A$1:$A$17,
  SUMIFS( Sheet1!$D$1:$D$17,
  Sheet1!$B$1:$B$17, "<=" & $A2, Sheet1!$C$1:$C$17, ">=" & $A2 ) )
  ```

  [image]

*Fig. 2*

It took aprox. less than 14 seconds to copy downwards and calculate the formulas in sheet 2.
As it can be seen in figures 1 and 2 none of the tables need to be sorted.

Comment: Nice example providing a `MATCHIFS`. Only pity that this will fail if more than one rows fulfills the `SUMIFS` conditions - yes you have noted this already with your first assuming. One could heal this with adding a `COUNTIFS` with the same conditions. If this `COUNTIFS`  is greater than 1 then the formula should result in `NA()` rather than in a wrong row.

Comment: @AxelRichter If there are more than one match the problem is not with the method but with integrity of the data. Your proposal seems to make sense, however It's a best practice to check the integrity of the master data before it's release to users.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both sheets start in A1, and First sheet ColumnB is sorted ascending, in Second sheet B2 please try:

```
=INDEX(First!A:A,MATCH(A2,First!B:B))
```

copied down to suit. It relies on inexact matching.

Comment: Thank u pnuts. Ive tried with intex formula. If i click and drag the to next adjecents cells, the cell references are also changing

Comment: I have pasted all the data in one sheet and tried the following formula  =INDEX($C28:C2077,SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2105<=E28:E2077),--($D$2105>=D28:D2077),ROW(F27:F2076)))    I got the required output. But if i click and drag the same formula to next cell, the cell references are changing. So i am not able to get correct output.

Comment: @pnuts: This solution does not respect that some values seems to be closed out. For example 270000 does not fall in any given range but your solution would return STE.

Comment: For the record, the SUMPRODUCT formula does work if you put the dollar signs in F$27:F$2076 etc. (as long as there is only one match!) but I wouldn't have done it this way.

Comment: No - I agree this conflicts with OP.

Comment: Actually it also gives the wrong answer when there is no match because then you get index (... , 0) which gives you the whole range so you get the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have a `Sheet1` like this:

[image]

note, the `Sheet1`is sorted by `Start_Pos`, `End_Pos` in ascending order.

and a `Sheet2` like this:

[image]

Then the formula in `Sheet2!B2` downwards could be:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,IF(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B:B)>IFERROR(MATCH(A2-(10^-10),Sheet1!C:C),0),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B:B),NA()))
```

See `MATCH`: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

The idea is: `MATCH` without exact matching (without parameter `match_type`) gets the row of the largest value which is smaller or equal the search value. So in the `Start_Pos` column it will get the row from which we can get the `S2_Symbol`. But from the `End_Pos` column it should get one row beforehand if the value is not outside the given ranges.

There is only one exception. If the value is exact the value in the `End_Pos` column, then it will return the same row as in the `Start_Pos` column. Considering this exception, we can search in the `End_Pos` column with a little bit smaller value. Thanks to Tom Sharpe for his comment.

The formula in `Sheet2!D2` downwards is:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MIN(IF($A2>=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$300000,IF($A2<=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$300000,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$300000),2^20+1))))}
```

this is an array formula which is exactly formulated respecting the requirements. But this is very bad in performance for using in much many cells. But using this, the `Sheet1` is not required to be sorted.

Benchmark test:

Have the following `Sheet1`:

[image]

Formulas:

`A2:A300002`: `="S"&(ROW(A1)-1)*10&"-"&(ROW(A1)-1)*10+7`

`B2:B300002`: `=(ROW(A1)-1)*10`

`C2:C300002`: `=B2+7`

and the following `Sheet2`:

[image]

Formulas:

`A2:A300002`: `=RANDBETWEEN(0,3000007)`

`B2:B300002`: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,IF(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B:B)>IFERROR(MATCH(A2-10^-9,Sheet1!C:C),0),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B:B),NA()))`

Note the `-10^-9` instead of `-10^-10` in previous version. This is because we have only 16 digits precision. In previous version  this was maximum 6 digits integer part and then 10 digits decimal part. Now it is maximum 7 digits integer part and then 9 digits decimal part.

Calculation after pressing `F9` in `Sheet2` takes ca. 2 s. (Excel 2007, Windows 7, 4 core processor).

Comment: Nice answer. Can I make one tiny comment? If the S1-location matched exactly with the end position, it wouldn't work because it would go to the current row instead of the previous row. I think you can fix it by subtracting one?

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone for something like this which gives you the first match if there is one:-

```
=INDEX(First!A:A,MATCH(1,(First!B:B<=A2)*(First!C:C>=A2),0))
```

assuming keys and start and end values are in a sheet called First and lookup values start in A2.

Array formula which must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

In response to the question from @pnuts about how long it will take, I have set up a similar benchmark with 300,000 rows in each sheet and it has reached 1% after 90 minutes, so it should take about 150 hours to reach 100% or roughly one week. This is to be expected as the number of computations required is (rows in sheet 1) X (rows in sheet 2)

```
300,000 X 300,000
```

but in fact because the multiplication applies to complete columns, I believe it is more correctly

```
300,000 X 1,048,576
```

i.e. > 300 billion.

A practical version which gives good response for smaller ranges is as follows:-

I define three named ranges Range1, Range2 and Range3

```
=First!$A$1:INDEX(First!$A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",First!$A:$A))

=First!$B$1:INDEX(First!$B:$B,MATCH(9.9E+307,First!$B:$B))

=First!$C$1:INDEX(First!$C:$C,MATCH(9.9E+307,First!$C:$C))
```

and the modified formula is

```
=INDEX(Range1,MATCH(1,(Range2<=A2)*(Range3>=A2),0))
```

I was thinking of deleting this answer, but would rather it stood as a counter-example.

Comment: OK no problem, I'll change it to bring it into line with the other two answers but it is very similar to the array formula in @Axel's answer.

Comment: No I won't have time to quantify it today but there is an appreciable delay as expected.